# PHP / MY SQL Different Data for Different Users

Tags: php, sql

I would like to display different data for different users on a custom made forum but I'm not quite sure the best way to go about it.

Here is the structure I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forums_forums` (
  `forum_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `forum_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `order_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `posts` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `replies` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `forum_description` text NOT NULL,
  `allow_topics` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `admin_only` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`forum_id`),
  KEY `forum_name` (`forum_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=102 ;
```

Each user by default should see all forums excluding admin and team specific ones. Some users will be part of a team but others will not so the ones that are part of the team should see all forums including their team specific one but not the admin one.

If the user is part of a team then the users table has an equal team id which matches with the forums team.

Here's what I have just now but I can't work out the best way to change it:

```
if ($GLOBALS["USER"]["team"] == 1) {
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forums_forums ORDER BY order_number");
} else {
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forums_forums WHERE admin_only=0 ORDER BY order_number");
}
WHILE ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
?>
<?if ($b["admin_only"] == 1) {?>
<tr bgcolor="#111111" height="100">
<?} else {?>
<tr bgcolor="#000000" height="100">
<?}?>
<td valign="top">
<blockquote style="margin:10px;">
<a href="/forums-view.php?forum_id=<?=$b["forum_id"]?>"><font color="#FFFFCC"><b><?=$b["forum_name"]?></b></font></a>
</blockquote>
</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;<b><?=number_format($b["posts"])?></b>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;<b><?=number_format($b["replies"])?></b>&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top">
<blockquote style="margin:10px;">
<?=$b["forum_description"]?>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
<?}?>
</table>
```

Comment: One tip: you'll be much better off changing STYLESHEETS based on admin status or my than adding conditionals inline in HTML to vary tag attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you really don't need to put PHP tags on every line, just keep it all in one block. I think the best thing you can do, since the forums table probably won't contain too many rows is to select them all, then add condition as to what's displayed. Also, I'm assuming a forum with no group has an id of 0.

```
$table = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forums_forums ORDER BY order_number ASC";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
    if(($_GLOBALS['users']['team'] == 1 && $row['admin_only']) || ($row['team'] > 1 && $_GLOBALS['users']['team'] == $row['team']) || ($row['team'] == 0 && $row['admin_only']))
    {
        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['forum_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['replies'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['posts'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['forum_description'].'</td>
            </tr>';

    }
}

echo '<table>'.$table.'</table>';
```

Bear in mind though, this is a really nasty way of doing things. If you want cleaner, more navigatable code then look into templating. You can write a template class yourself without much difficultly. What you should be looking to do then is to have a template with all the HTML in a row, when repeat that row as often as you need it.

Also, you should take a look at some of the data types for your table. If admin_only can only be 1 or 0 for example, it should be a TINYINT with length of 1.